# jQuery issue - #<an Object> has no method

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, slider

I've tried a veriety of jQuery plugins recently and I keep getting this error …

[image: has no method]
<sub>(source: [shaunbellis.co.uk](https://shaunbellis.co.uk/stackoverflow/jserror.png))</sub>

… regardless of what plugin I try to use.

I've checked the links to the JS files which are all there and working fine. I'm using Drupal if that makes any difference.

I've run the plugins away from the main site to demonstrate that they are working and that I am doing things right with 100% success.

Any ideas?

Update:

My jQuery file called in the footer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          

$('#footer_holder').hide();

// Fancy Box
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true,
    'titlePosition' : 'over',
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200, 
    'overlayShow'   :   false,
});

$("#homepage_slider").easySlider({
    auto: true, 
    continuous: true,
});
```

});

*note - fancy box works fine (unless the easySlider code is above it). jQuery is sorted out by Drupal. I'm running version 1.4

Comment: Where are you running this? Is it wrapped in a `.ready()` function?

Comment: +1 for the image :) - please provide the markup where you call jQuery & plugin code

Comment: I've updated the question to show the info that's been asked.

Comment: I've gotten this error a couple of times as I learn JQuery and landed on this question twice now, it turns out I was forgetting '$' infront of the (#section)...hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ignore me. I'm sorry everyone. I'd mistyped the url of the script. Thanks to Simon Ainley for the prod in the right direction.

Sorry again. Thanks.

Comment: … and thanks of course to jAndy and Pekka.

(I was talking to Simon using an IM client).

Comment: I just came here after spending a good half an hour on the same problem - never have I felt so stupid!

Comment: Is it possible to mark Simon Ainley's answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 26):

This problem can also arise if you include jQuery more than once.

Comment: Oh, my, god. This was it, for me. Another plugin was loading its own jQuery version. Thank you.

Comment: @Aleks, me too:)
Every control which thinks he need jquery includes jquery.
This solved my problem.

Everyone - try check $.fn (or jQuery.fn). If array is empty - than it's almost all about mistyped url, or including jquery more than once.

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem, or one that looked superficially similar, yesterday.  It turned out that I wasn't being careful when mixing jQuery and prototype. I found several solutions at http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries. I opted for

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

but there are other reasonable options described there.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone else arriving at this question:

I was performing the most simple jQuery, trying to hide an element:

```
('#fileselection').hide();
```

and I was getting the same type of error, "**Uncaught TypeError: Object #fileselection has no method 'hide'**

Of course, now it is obvious, but I just left off the jQuery indicator '$'.  The code should have been:

```
$('#fileselection').hide();
```

This fixes the no-brainer problem.  I hope this helps someone save a few minutes debugging!

Comment: what does this have to do with the question? hide is a built-in, not a plugin.

Comment: @FlavorScape, the question wasn't related to a plugin at all... it was related to the error message.  Re-read the question; his plug-in information is just additional information.  None of the other answers talk about plug-ins either.  Most people arrive at this question because they are googling "Uncaught TypeError: Object #fileselection has no method 'hide'", and this is another item to check if you have spent too many hours programming to see the `$` missing.

Comment: It's answering the wrong question. The OP clearly indicates that the reference to jquery is there, so your solution has nothing to do with the question. It's the answer to a different question. It is quite obvious that string "#fileselection" has no method hide, which is not as obvious as conflicting jQuery versions or plugin conflicts between libraries.

Comment: @FlavorScape of course, you are welcome to your opinion.  But as I mentioned, the purpose of StackOverflow is for finding answers to questions, even if they are slightly tangential to the original OP's direct question.  Seeing how this question has been viewed 98116 times as of this writing and this answer has been found useful so far 11 times, the answer stands for itself.  By downvoting it, you feel it has no value, which isn't getting the bigger picture.  Thank you for your point of view, though.

Comment: But that is not the same type of error.  The reason people searching for your term get here is because YOU PUT THE TERM HERE in your answer that does not address the question. So to the other 98111 users this is noise that detracts from valid answers.  Answering with tangential question in mind adds noise to those trying to solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 5):

This problem may also come up if you include different versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

This usually has to do with a selector not being used properly. Check and make sure that you are using the jQuery selectors like intended. For example I had this problem when creating a click method:

```
$("[editButton]").click(function () {
    this.css("color", "red");
});
```

Because I was not using the correct selector method $(this) for jQuery it gave me the same error.

So simply enough, check your selectors!