# XML not validating?

Tags: xml, validation

Never really worked with XML before, but how come this isn't validating:

http://test.ipalaces.org/palnfo/template.xml

---

With w3schools i get `Error: Object # has no method 'load'`

Comment: This parsed fine for me using IE.  This could be an issue with the w3schools site.  What technology / language are you using to parse this in your application?  .NET, Web, Java, python, etc?

Comment: With w3schools? Seriously? You should read [this](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: Link is Dead! Question is not useful anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You're using Chrome, aren't you? Your XML is fine; the w3schools validator is not.

Consider using a different online validator, or installing one locally. You may even find you've got a basic one installed somewhere already, depending on your OS (xmllint came pre-installed on my Mac, for example.)

Incidentally, you're also probably not actually "validating", technically, rather checking for "well-formedness". To validate you'd need a DTD or XSD.

Answer (score 2):

What you got here is a **Javascript** error.

From the w3schools validator :

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
document.write("<h2>Result of Validating: http://test.ipalaces.org/palnfo/template.xml</h2>");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async="false";
xmlDoc.validateOnParse="true";
xmlDoc.load("http://test.ipalaces.org/palnfo/template.xml"); // <--- ERROR HERE
```

### 2 solutions :

- Stop using IE (whatever version you're using) or any other uncompatible (with this validator) web browser you're using.
- Stop using w3schools validator which sucks. (**use [the w3c one](http://www.w3.org/2001/03/webdata/xsv) which is the *more official* or [this one](http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/)**)

EDIT :

I'll add that, in general, please, avoid w3schools and go to *official* manual or website.

First because http://w3fools.com and then because there's better! For everything about HTML, XHTML, XML, search for it and "w3c" in google. For Javascript, use "MDC"+whatever-you're-looking-for, for php, go to [their manual](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Seems ok to me.  When I ran it against the [w3schools validator](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_validate.asp) I got this message:

> Result of Validating:
>   http://test.ipalaces.org/palnfo/template.xml

Doesn't really tell you anything but no obvious error message.  How are you validating it?

Also, this might be a shot in the dark but are you sure this isn't a jQuery error?  I did a quick search of your error message and found two SO posts that had very similar error messages:

- [jQuery issue - #<an Object> has no method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988485/jquery-issue-an-object-has-no-method)
- [Weird Chrome prototype/jQuery conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833883/weird-chrome-prototype-jquery-conflict)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an error on their javascript.

It seems to be fixed. It validated with me.  Can you try again ?

You used this URL `http://www.w3schools.com/site/site_validate.asp` right ? Fourth section Right ?

It also depends on the browser you use to access the validation page because as you might know different browser load XML files in different ways.  What browser did you use ?