# 'effect' works fine in jsfiddle but not in live code ([object Object] has no method 'effect' )

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

Related, but not a fix: [jQuery issue - #<an Object> has no method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988485/jquery-issue-an-object-has-no-method)

I'm getting an error `Object [object Object] has no method 'effect'` when I try to use the `effect` function in jquery (doc http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight). It's working fine in JSFiddle but it errors out when I run the site in Chrome or IE. The div gets shown but the effect call throws an error.

Live version can be found here:  http://jsfiddle.net/jcollum/HK625/

Html

```
<a id=showHowThisWorks >How does this all work?</a>    
<div id="howThisWorks" style="display: none; ">    
  <p>It works fine</p>
</div>
```

And this coffeescript:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#howThisWorks').hide()

  $('#showHowThisWorks').click ->
    $div = $('#howThisWorks')
    $div.toggle();
    $div.effect("highlight", {}, 10000)
    return

  return
```

Which looks like this in JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#howThisWorks').hide();
    $('#showHowThisWorks').click(function() {
      var $div;
      $div = $('#howThisWorks');
      $div.toggle();
      $div.effect("highlight", {}, 6000);
    });
  });
```

I've tried making the $div a jquery selector on that line instead of using the variable. I've tried wrapping $div in $(). I'm still getting the error on the real version of the page. Same result in Chrome and IE9. Clearly I'm missing something about how jquery objects behave.

Comment: Does `toggle()` work? In other words, if you remove the `effect()` call, it works?

Comment: @Dave yes, toggle is working fine

Comment: I was hoping I just missed `jQuery.fx.off` so I tried setting that to false but no go. Using `$div.fadeToggle(400)` did what I want, but I still can't figure out why `effect` won't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that jQuery UI is not getting deployed locally: check in Firebug/Chrome etc. to verify.

`.toggle()` is part of core jQuery, `.effect()` is part of jQuery UI: in order for this not to be working, jQuery UI must not be present.

Comment: +1. All jQuery objects have the same methods attached, so the only explanation for the error jcollum is seeing is that no plugin has defined the `effect` method for jQuery.

Comment: Seems that that was it. Not clear from the docs which library it is in ... on top of that if you remove the reference to jquery ui (which is included by default) on jsfiddle the code still works with no errors that I can see (even after hitting Update). Blech.

Comment: @jcollum No sweat. Could be a caching issue, or something jsfiddle-peculiar :)