# JQuery highlight won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I'm using JQuery to use a highlight effect as discribed on the docs side of JQuery itself.
[JQuery HighLight](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight)

But when using this on a tr or td element, I'm getting this exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'effect'
```

I tried to use a simple effect like hide() and that effect did work.
Could anybody help me out here? What am I missing here?

This is the code I'm using:

```
  $('.small_form').live "ajax:success", (event, xhr)->
    $(@).parents('tr').effect("highlight", {}, 3000)
```

It is in coffe script, I also made sure the ajax request works. Because I got other effect working using this event.

Comment: It's hard to determine the problem when you don't share any of your code.

Comment: You should load jQuery UI.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['effect' works fine in jsfiddle but not in live code (\[object Object\] has no method 'effect' )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114357/effect-works-fine-in-jsfiddle-but-not-in-live-code-object-object-has-no-met)

Comment: Can you share your code please? It appears that either your jQuery library is not loaded yet when you try to execute its methods or you call jQuery methods on DOM elements and not on $ function.

Comment: @undefined: Doesn't the hide effect also need JQuery UI to work? In either case I made sure JQuery UI is loaded

Comment: @Niels No, `hide` belongs to jQuery core, you should load both jQuery core and it's UI library.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance I use a gem in my project which also loads this script 'jquery_ujs.js'. Which I mistakingly saw for JQuery UI. Adding JQuery UI obviously did the job thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add this into your page after loading jQuery.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

The effect method is part of jQuery UI, and is required when trying to use it!